# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0.1 and Windows Storage Emulator 3.1.0 results in (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm having problems with the Storage emulator after upgrading my Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library to version 4.0.1.

The following code:

```
var client = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString).CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = client.GetTableReference("TableName");
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The call to `table.CreateIfNotExists()` throws a `StorageException`, with detail:

> Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> InnerException.Response: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not
>   in the correct format.

I am aware of the previous issue with using the 3.x client libraries with version 2.0 of the emulator (or something along those lines) and was able to work around it.

Connecting to real table service works fine, so it's something to do with the emulator.

Any ideas?

Edit: for those looking, the direct download link for the 3.2 version of the emulator is here - http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/F/1/0F162192-CDE5-413D-8DC0-37F41300B47B/WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi

Comment: You're mixing library versions, right? Why not upgrade everything? The Azure APIs seem to be in perma-flux, so I'm not sure that mixed versioning is too much of a good idea. Why are you in this situation?

Comment: That's the latest version of the emulator, right?  It was installed as part of the Azure SDK 2.3.  As far as I was aware, the client libraries and the emulator have always been different versions.  In short, I think I already have the latest of everything.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I thought you were freestyling on versions! Ignore me. I would double check that your client-libraries are fully up to date though.

Comment: Can you trace the request/response through Fiddler? This should give you an idea about what headers are being sent.

Comment: Have been trying to do that.  I set my connection string to: `UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://ipv4.fiddler`, and Fiddler is running, but I get an exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'ipv4.fiddler'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice for troubleshooting emulator problems is to first make sure you have the latest version of the emulator installed. A 400 response often means you have a newer version of the client libraries and are attempting to perform an operation not yet implemented in your version of the emulator.

For more information on the latest version see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/16/microsoft-azure-storage-client-library-and-tooling-updates-teched-2014.aspx).

Jason

Comment: Thanks Jason. I managed to find the download.  I must say, while the information IS there, it's not really obvious.  There is a bit of information on the NuGet page for the client libraries - maybe some more info there would be good.

Comment: Hi Brendan - Quick clarification. When you say the information IS there - do you mean the information on what a 400 could mean for the emulator - or something else? I definitely want to help improve this experience for you...

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of mention of the new version of the emulator and a link to its download references from the 4.0.1 client libraries.  Look, maybe it's just me, but it took quite a while to connect the dots and find the links for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped by the same problem for several hours. I had **Azure SDK 2.3** configured against my solution and was running the old **v1.7 StorageClient** - worth noting is that everything worked find but I needed to upgrade the storage library to use some new features. Anyway after removing the v1.7 StorageClient and doing a NuGet on the new storage library I found I had this error. In the end I tried everything:

- Double-checked names of my queues
- Manually checked every bin/obj folder for the storage client assembly and removed any left lying around
- Rebooted - because I was getting desperate

In the end I just reinstalled the v2.3 Azure SDK and it fixed it. No errors came up when I reinstalled, it just worked as expected.

So if in doubt do try an SDK reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

A 400 error in itself doesn't tell you much.  Grab the exceptions RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode, RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode and RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage, this will help you see more detail (code sample below).

Before making calls to the emulator also make sure you're aware of the various naming constraints (such as forbidden characters in partition keys, table names, etc), the data types supported (dates must be UTC, decimals aren't supported, etc) and finally the differences between what the emulator and Azure support, as there are a couple.

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (StorageException ex)
{
    ApplicationException aex = new ApplicationException("StorageException in SaveTransactionsToAzure()", ex);
    aex.Source = "SaveTransactionsToAzure()";
    aex.Data.Add("HttpStatusCode", ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode);
    aex.Data.Add("ErrorCode", ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode);
    aex.Data.Add("ErrorMessage", ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage);
    throw aex;
}
```